# adding header row before each column size change in table generated automatically

Tags: php

Ive got the following code.  It loops through data from an array and adds up all data that has the same size and adds the rowspan number into the table automatically.

### Automatically Add new header row

Now what I need to do is to be able to add a new "header row" ( `echo "<th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Thickness</th><th>Price</th>";` ) before the size changes and then display new sizes after additional header row.  This will help when viewing the table once a lot of data is added to table.

**What would I add to make this occur automatically and where would I add it?**
I'm thinking it would work off of `$output[$sizeStartRow][1]` but I'm not sure where to add to the code.

### Code

```
//dummy data array instead of your database output, expanded a little to help with testing:
$data = array(
  array("name" => "item1", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".020", "price" => "$25"),
  array("name" => "item2", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".025", "price" => "$28"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".080", "price" => "$50"),
  array("name" => "item3", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".030", "price" => "$30"),
  array("name" => "item4", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".040", "price" => "$40"),
  array("name" => "item5", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item7", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item8", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item9", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item10", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item11", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
);

$output = array(); //this is ready to hold the table cells
$prevSizeVal = null; //holds the size value from the previous row
$sizeStartRow = 0; //keep track of the row where a rowspanned size cell started

//this is in place of your while loop, you won't need totalRows because the fetch_assoc function takes care of this for you. This is just for the mockup.
$counter = 0; 
$totalRows = count($data);

while ($counter < $totalRows) {
  $cp = $data[$counter]; //to get an equivalent row variable that the fetch_assoc loop gives you
  $row = array(); //create a new output row

  //get the boring ones out of the way
  $row[0] = "<td>".$cp["name"]."</td>";
  $row[2] = "<td>".$cp["thickness"]."</td>";
  $row[3] = "<td>".$cp["price"]."</td>";

  $sizeCol = "";

  //now for the fun part with the size column
  if ($prevSizeVal != $cp["size"]) {
      $sizeStartRow = $counter;
      $sizeCol = '<td rowspan="1">'.$cp["size"].'</td>';
  }
  else
  {
      //change the rowspan value at the start position, as we know it's increased
      $output[$sizeStartRow][1] = preg_replace('/rowspan="[\d]+"/', 'rowspan="'.($counter-$sizeStartRow +1).'"', $output[$sizeStartRow][1]);
  }

  $row[1] = $sizeCol;

  $output[$counter] = $row; //add the row to the output. We may change the rowspan of the size cell later.
  $prevSizeVal = $cp["size"]; //update the previous size value
  $counter++;
}

//now we've built the output array of cells, we can echo them into a table.
echo "<table>";
echo "<th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Thickness</th><th>Price</th>";
//loop the rows
for ($i = 0; $i < count($output); $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  //loop the cells within the current row
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($output[$i]); $j++)
  {
    $cell = $output[$i][$j];
    echo $cell; //some variables will be empty (because we didn't create them because we knew there was a row-spanned cell above them, so nothing will be echoed in those cases
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

### Link to code

https://eval.in/961231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you reorganize your original array and your loop, you can insert the header row easily enough. Try this:

```
$data = array(
  array("name" => "item1", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".020", "price" => "$25"),
  array("name" => "item2", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".025", "price" => "$28"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".080", "price" => "$50"),
  array("name" => "item3", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".030", "price" => "$30"),
  array("name" => "item4", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".040", "price" => "$40"),
  array("name" => "item5", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item7", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item8", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item9", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item10", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item11", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
);
# Create storage array
$transfer   =   [];
# Loop $data
foreach($data as $row) {
    # Make the size the key value
    $transfer[$row['size']][]   =   $row;
}
# Now just loop over the first array which is the grouping
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach($transfer as $block => $rows): ?>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    # Set the default rowspan as empty
    $rowspan    =   false;
    # This indicates an easy way to note that you need a new header row
    $start      =   true;
    # Loop each rows now
    foreach($rows as $row):
        if(!empty($start)) {
            # Assign rowspan
            $rowspan    =   count($rows);
            # This is the first row, so make sure the start is set false
            # for subsequent rows
            $start      =   false;
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
        <?php if(!empty($rowspan)): ?>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; $rowspan = false; ?>"><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <?php endif ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['thickness'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Gives you:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td rowspan="5">2 x 2</td>
        <td>.020</td>
        <td>$25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>.025</td>
        <td>$28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>.080</td>
        <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>.030</td>
        <td>$30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>.040</td>
        <td>$40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item5</td>
        <td rowspan="4">3 x 2</td>
        <td>.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item7</td>
        <td>.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item8</td>
        <td>.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item9</td>
        <td rowspan="3">4 x 2</td>
        <td>.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item10</td>
        <td>.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item11</td>
        <td>.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your question regarding how the `$data` array is generated, I would do this part first (going with PDO here as example):

```
$data = [];
while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data[$result['size']][] = $result;
}
```

Then you can remove this part:

```
#Create storage array
$transfer  =   [];
# Loop $data
foreach($data as $row) {
    # Make the size the key value
    $transfer[$row['size']][] =   $row;
}
```

And change this part:

```
<?php foreach($transfer as $block => $rows): ?>
```

to use the `$data` again:

```
<?php foreach($data as $block => $rows): ?>
```

Comment: I wasn't planning on getting different code so...how would I incorporate that into a query while loop?  I used the data array as an example.  Also, does your code operate better than the code I put in?

Comment: You can benchmark it if you want, but it's easier to section out your array at the beginning then to try and come up with some elaborate middle part to try and insert a row mid loop.

Comment: If your original array is already broken up into it's groupings, you just insert a new row after every group starts.

Comment: I will also go out on a limb and say what I have will probably benchmark better. Though we each have 3 loops, you are using `count($output)` in your `for` loop which runs that `count()` on every iteration. The `count()` I use only runs as many groups as there are (in this case 3 times). I also don't use any regex in mine, which also eats up a little time and memory.

Comment: Can you rewrite how this would be used in a mysqli query while loop?  I just don't know what to put in the while loop and what to put outside it.  I used the data array for example purposes only.  I'll probably go with your solution if it benchmarks better.

Comment: Oooh, I see. The `$data` array is actually made by `while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` type thing. Let me revise...

Comment: ignore my last comment if you saw it...I deleted it...I missed smoething

Comment: Ok, I was going to say that you have something not right then but if you missed something, that would make sense!

Comment: I asked a new question based on this code.  Its related to something outside the parameters of my question here, so I posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941363/how-can-i-add-more-than-one-automated-rowspan