# How can I add more than one automated rowspan

Tags: php

I've got the following code.  I haven't fully learned how to modify it to meet the needs of my project as of yet; however, I'm slowly learning the different elements to this code.  I had never done anything like this before now, so this is all somewhat new to me.

***Right now,*** the code gets information from, in this example, a data array.  In reality, its from a database; however, this just makes it easier to work with.  It loops through the entire array and after all the data is collected, it builds the table and automatically sets the rowspan of the "size" column to the number of rows needed based on the number of entries in the array for that specific size.  Once it detects a new size, it adds a new header row and starts over.

### Question:

But what if I wanted it to calculate another column too **What do I need to modify to be able to have more than one column using the automated rowspan uniquely?**

So not only would the column for "size" calculate automatically, but the column for "thickness" would also individually calculate.  To get something like this...

```
----------------------------------------
name     size   thickness    price
----------------------------------------
1    |         |          |      $25    |
-----                      -------------
2    |   2x2   |          |     $27     |
------                    ---------------
3    |         |   .160   |      $30    |
---------------           ---------------
4    |   2x3   |          |      $40    |
----------------          ---------------  
5    |  3x3    |          |      $55    |
-----------------------------------------
```

In the example above, both the size (2x2) and the thickness (.160) both were added a rowspan but they calculated the number of rows needed in rowspan automatically.

### Code

```
$data = array(
  array("name" => "item1", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".020", "price" => "$25"),
  array("name" => "item2", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".025", "price" => "$28"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".080", "price" => "$50"),
  array("name" => "item3", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".030", "price" => "$30"),
  array("name" => "item4", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".040", "price" => "$40"),
  array("name" => "item5", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item7", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item8", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item9", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item10", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item11", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
);
# Create storage array
$transfer   =   [];
# Loop $data
foreach($data as $row) {
    # Make the size the key value
    $transfer[$row['size']][]   =   $row;
}
# Now just loop over the first array which is the grouping
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach($transfer as $block => $rows): ?>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    # Set the default rowspan as empty
    $rowspan    =   false;
    # This indicates an easy way to note that you need a new header row
    $start      =   true;
    # Loop each rows now
    foreach($rows as $row):
        if(!empty($start)) {
            # Assign rowspan
            $rowspan    =   count($rows);
            # This is the first row, so make sure the start is set false
            # for subsequent rows
            $start      =   false;
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
        <?php if(!empty($rowspan)): ?>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; $rowspan = false; ?>"><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <?php endif ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['thickness'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create some markers to indicate that you need to check for rowcounts/rowspan on the thickness:

```
$data = array(
  array("name" => "item1", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".020", "price" => "$25"),
  array("name" => "item2", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".025", "price" => "$28"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".080", "price" => "$50"),
  array("name" => "item3", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".030", "price" => "$30"),
  array("name" => "item4", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".040", "price" => "$40"),
  array("name" => "item5", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item7", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item8", "size" => "3 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item9", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item10", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
  array("name" => "item11", "size" => "4 x 2", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43"),
);
# Create storage array
$transfer   =   [];
# Loop $data
foreach($data as $row) {
    # Make the size the key value
    $transfer[$row['size']][]   =   $row;
}
# Now just loop over the first array which is the grouping
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach($transfer as $block => $rows): ?>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    # Set the default rowspan as empty
    $rowspan    =   false;
    # This indicates an easy way to note that you need a new header row
    $start      =   true;
    # This will be set on each new thickness, but you want to reset it on 
    # each size group as well.
    if(isset($thickness))
        unset($thickness);
    # Loop each rows now
    foreach($rows as $row):
        if(!empty($start)) {
            # Assign rowspan
            $rowspan    =   count($rows);
            # This is the first row, so make sure the start is set false
            # for subsequent rows
            $start      =   false;
        }
        # Create the rowspan here for thickness 
        $thickrowcount  =   
        $new            =   false;
        # If not set, set it (indicates first use of thickness)
        if(!isset($thickness)) {
            $thickness  =   $row['thickness'];
            $new        =   true;
        }
        # If it's already set and doesn't match, consider it's new
        if(($row['thickness'] != $thickness)) {
            $thickness  =   $row['thickness'];
            $new        =   true;
        }
        # Iterate the rows in this group and determine how many are this thickness.
        if($new)
            $thickrowcount  =   array_sum(array_map(function($v) use ($thickness){ return ($v['thickness'] == $thickness)? 1 : 0; },$rows));
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
        <?php if(!empty($rowspan)): ?>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; $rowspan = false; ?>"><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if(!empty($thickrowcount)): # Write rowspan here ?>
        <td<?php if($thickrowcount > 1): ?> rowspan="<?php echo $thickrowcount ?>"<?php endif ?>><?php echo $row['thickness'] ?></td>
        <?php endif ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Gives you:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td rowspan="5">2 x 2</td>
        <td>.020</td>
        <td>$25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>.025</td>
        <td>$28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>.080</td>
        <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>.030</td>
        <td>$30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>.040</td>
        <td>$40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item5</td>
        <td rowspan="4">3 x 2</td>
        <td rowspan="4">.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item7</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item8</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Thickness</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item9</td>
        <td rowspan="3">4 x 2</td>
        <td rowspan="3">.050</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item10</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item11</td>
        <td>$43</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```